# Synchronized PRNGs?

Tags: random-number-generator

I'd like two PRNGs with the following properties:

Each produces a stream of cryptographically secure pseudo-random numbers.

Each has an index that would start at 0 and increase by 1 for every random bit produced by the device.

If, at any given time, the indices of the two devices are the same, then the next random bit produced by the two devices will be the same.

Is something like this possible? If it can't be done in software, is there any sort of hardware that can do this?

Comment: CTR mode with the same key sounds like the best option

Comment: As far as I can tell, *any* deterministic pseudorandom number generator will have the property you're asking for. If that's not the case, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ​ Just track [input and [which bit of the output]] for a [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), such as [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

http://pub.ist.ac.at/crypto/pubs/GPR14.pdf